# How to add Dynamic Image url for Product in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

I am using a third party service to generate product images. How can I use a URL for product images instead of uploading media into server.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't supported natively but there are ways to achieve it.

If the URLs are dynamic, e.g based on sku, you could remove the native product images from your template and replace it with a generated img tag pointing to the image.

If the URLs cannot be worked out dynamically you could add a new attribute to your products to hold the URL. You would still get rid of native images from your template but replace it with an img tag built off this attribute